# h5py - Python Package install error in Windows 10 64bit

Tags: python-3.x, pip, anaconda, h5py

I have succeeded to install h5py package via pp and anaconda on windows 10 64bit, Python 3.5.1.

```
conda install h5py
```

But I couldn't execute python server. Here is the screenshot to show my trouble.

[image]

I need your help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can get some trouble in installing the python packages on windows by conda or pip. Please download 64-bit h5py from here and try to install it.

[link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#h5py)